# Accessing a value from a SQLite.swift array

Tags: sqlite.swift

How do you get at a row of type SQLite.Row using the row number?

This is order to populate a picker using the results Array.

Thanks

```
var allCountries:Array<Any>?
let countries = Table("Country")
let id = Expression<Int64>("rowid")
let name = Expression<String>("Name")
let code = Expression<String>("Code")


func pickerView(_ pickerView:UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component:Int) -> String?{

        return allCountries?[row].*somethingHere* as String
//The array is populated with rows of type SQLite.Row
}

func getCountries() -> Array<Any>{
    var  results:Array<Any>?
    do{

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "location", ofType: "sqlite")
        let db = try Connection(path!, readonly: true)
        results = Array(try db.prepare(countries))
    }
    catch{
        print("Error")
    }
    return results!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - needed to return an `Array<SQLite.Row>`, not `<Any>`.